# Элементы прозрачны в дизайнере

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

Столкнулся с такой проблемой все элементы которые я ставлю прозрачны.visual studio 2015
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в margin. Попробуйте удалить.

Comment: Почему-то не это кажется странным...

Comment: такая проблема при создание любого проекта, для винфона. Гуглил есть у людей такая же проблема но решения не нашел. Это скорее баг самой студии но я пробовал удалить все свои студии и поставить по новой не помогло.